# postgres trigger creation

Tags: postgresql, triggers

How do I only create a trigger if it does not exist?

When I do create or replace, I get a syntax error so I am looking for a way to test for the existence of a trigger.

I can always select * from pg_trigger, but I am sure there is a more suitable way.

Thanks

Comment: it's always a good idea to mention what version of postgres you are using

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Postgres can conditionally drop a trigger - see [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-droptrigger.html).  Do this *before* creating the trigger, then it will always work.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytrigger ON mytable;
```

As Jack points out in the comments, this feature has only been available since 8.2; this has been out for more than four years though, so it should be available in your version.

Comment: @El Yobo, worth mentioning that this feature was introduced in 8.2

Comment: @El Yobo It's hard to be sure how many are still using 8.1 - I think a key factor to consider is that it is the default install on RHEL5 and I suspect that means use is still widespread

Comment: Yeah, I had the ... pleasure ... of setting up a RHEL server the other day.  I thought Debian stable was behind the curve, but RHEL takes the cake.

Comment: this is a great answer for dropping but how do I check if a trigger exists before creating it is really what I am after

Comment: @reza: if you always drop it first, you will always be able to create it safely.  This safely ensures that it never exists when you try to create it.

Comment: @ElYobo but what if I do not want to drop a trigger because it is operational now? If I drop it then until it is created again, the functionality will be lost, right? Does not sound like a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: @KirillG. It is not operational within the context of transaction. Dropping and recreating can only be a problem if the implementations differ. But at that point you can't create a trigger safely anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER (NameOfTrigger) AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON (NameOfTable)
```

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS (NameOfTrigger) ON (NameOfTable);
```